# Share webpage via SMS

Tags: wordpress, mobile, sms

My client wants to be able to share webpages on their website via SMS. They want to be able to send any page (on their site) to anyone's smartphone while they're using a desktop/laptop. It's a WordPress site and I don't see a viable option for this in plugins. I know there are a lot of social share plugins, I've used many of them, but I don't see this option. I don't want whatsapp, or something like that and it doesn't have to be a wordpress plugin.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to send a link by SMS, not a page.

It's easy with AT&T / iPhone, but I don't know about other carriers / phones.

From [Send email as text message](https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/wireless/KM1061254%20/)

`Compose a new email and use the recipient's 10-digit wireless phone number, followed by @txt.att.net. For example, 5551234567@txt.att.net`

Comment: Thanks for the input WhereDidmyBrainGo. I need to be able to send an SMS to smartphones, regardless of carrier, from my website, using my laptop.

Comment: I found Twilio, a commercial service that looks easy. But I cannot understand what it costs. See [Add SMS to your Web App (with 4 lines of code)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/add-sms-to-your-web-app-in-4-lines-of-code.html)